# SwiftUI How to create settings like in Pages

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to create settings style like in Pages? I do not know how to style it. I tried code bellow, but it is not what I want.
I do not want whole form content. I want only achieve same style - frames, border radius, background colors etc.

I Want:

[image]

I have:

[image]

My current code:

```
let sizes = ["500 MB", "1 GB", "3 GB"]
@Binding var dataSize: String

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section("Data size") {
                    Picker("Data size", selection: $dataSize) {
                        ForEach(sizes, id: \.self) { size in
                            Text(size)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 115)
            .clipShape(CustomShape(radius: 15))
            .shadow(radius: 20)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

Comment: You want us to produce the entire code? You gave us one line of UI and said it's not what u wanted. Of course, that's not what you wanted.

Comment: try to make your question more specific regarding what requirements you need and add more code so it will be easily to debug it, from what i understand and i doubt i do, you need to make your form with different sections and each section has its own details you need to create separate subviews for each section so it can be easily handled and more readable

Comment: Hello, I do not want whole form, ti was not meant about content. I want only achieve same style, frames, border radius, background colors etc.

Comment: @tkantor81 do check the answer i added it should get what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i mentioned before use the sections inside the form so you can add whatever you need inside each section, as you see in the example i can create different views inside each section

```
struct ContentView: View {
let sizes = ["500 MB", "1 GB", "3 GB"]
@Binding var dataSize: String
@State  var isOpen = true
@State var slideValue = 0.0

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            // only one form
            Form {
                // different section
                Section("sec 1") {
                    Picker("Data size", selection: $dataSize) {
                        ForEach(sizes, id: \.self) { size in
                            Text(size)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
                // different section
                Section("sec 2") {
                    Button("button 1") {
                        print("do action")
                    }.foregroundColor(.black).frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center).background(Color.red).cornerRadius(10)
                    Slider(value: $slideValue)
                    
                }                    // different section
                
                Section("sec 3") {
                    Toggle("Show toggle", isOn: $isOpen)
                }
                
                // different section
                Section("sec 4") {
                    
                    Button("button 2") {
                        print("do action")
                    }.foregroundColor(.black).frame(width: 200, height: 70, alignment: .center).background(Color.blue).cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
            }.frame(width:500,height: 700, alignment: .center).background(Color.clear)
            
            
                .shadow(radius: 20)
        }
    }.frame(width: 500, height: 700, alignment: .center)
}


 }
```

[image]

Comment: Bigger form width did the trick. Thank you